# What is the best way to deal with nullable string columns in LinqToSql?

Tags: string, linq-to-sql, nullable

Assume you have a table with a nullable varchar column. When you try to filter the table, you would use (pFilter is parameter):

```
var filter = pFilter;
var dataContext = new DBDataContext();
var result = dataContext.MyTable.Where(x=>x.MyColumn == filter).ToList();
```

Now, what if there is a keyword that means "All Nulls". The code would look like:

```
var filter = pFilter != "[Nulls]" ? pFilter : null;
var dataContext = new DBDataContext();
var result = dataContext.MyTable.Where(x=>x.MyColumn == filter).ToList();
```

But this doesn't work. Apparently, a String with value of null is... not null?

However, what do work is this code:

```
var filter = pFilter != "[Nulls]" ? pFilter : null;
var dataContext = new DBDataContext();
var result = dataContext.MyTable.Where(x=>x.MyColumn == filter || (filter == null && x.MyColumn == null)).ToList();
```

The workaround did not convinced me, that's why my question is: What is the best way to deal with nullable string columns in LinqToSql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `String.Equals` that will make LINQ handle null appropriately on the generated SQL query

```
var result = dataContext.MyTable
                        .Where(x => String.Equals(x.MyColumn, filter))
                        .ToList();
```

Edit:

If you use `==` LINQ will generate the query for the general case `WHERE [column] = @parameter` but on SQL NULL does not match NULL, the proper way to test for NULL is `[column] IS NULL`.

With `String.Equals` LINQ has enough information to translate the method to the appropiate sentence in each case, what means:

if you pass a non-null string it will be

```
WHERE ([column] IS NOT NULL) AND ([column] = @parameter)
```

and if it is null

```
WHERE [column] IS NULL
```

Comment: Any idea why it doesn't work? I mean a technical explanation.

Comment: @Marco I updated the answer.  Basically is how the LINQ to SQL provider treats `==`.